# Linq Joining IEnumerable(Of Struct) to IEnumerable(of object)

Tags: linq, join, linq-to-objects

With class RoleRecord (Guid RoleId, string RoleName,...) I am trying to get a new list of Name where the RoleId matches a list of Guid

```
IEnumerable<RoleRecord> roles;
IEnumerable<Guid> roleIds;
```

I was thinking about avoiding the nested for loops, and along the lines of :

```
            var query = 
            from rowA in roles
            join rowB in roleIds
            on rowA.RoleId equals rowB.????
            select { rowA.RoleName };
```

I tried to wrap the guid in a class too, but cant even build it because the syntax is wrong.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
var query = 
            from rowA in roles
            where roleIds.Contains(rowA.RoleId)
            select  rowA.RoleName;
```

Answer (score 5):

I would personally *not* use Jeremy's answer if you've got a significant number of Guids. If a join is what you really want to express - you just need:

```
var query = from rowA in roles
            join rowB in roleIds on rowA.RoleId equals rowB
            select rowA.RoleName;
```

Alternatively, create a set of role IDs first:

```
HashSet<Guid> validRoleIds = new HashSet<Guid>(roleIds);
var query = from rowA in roles
            where validRoleIds.Contains(rowA.RoleId)
            select rowA.RoleName;
```

The advantage is that then you don't need to do a linear search through every valid role ID for every role. That's not an issue if you *know* you don't have many roles or role IDs, but generally a hashing approach will be more effective.

Note that the join will use a hash as well internally.

Comment: Appreciate the reply, thanks.  Am pretty new to linq but liking it more and more.